# WinUI 3 ListView - how to handle selected item with mvvm C++

Tags: c#, c++, xaml, c++-winrt

I am looking for a solution for my WinRT C++ desktop app to handle list view item selection in my view model. I can bind to the SelectionChanged event

```
SelectionChanged="{x:Bind MainViewModel.OnClick}"
```

but I don't know who clicked.

The C# solution uses `xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"`

```
    <ListView>
        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectItemCommand}" />
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <ListViewItem Content="Item #1" />
        <ListViewItem Content="Item #2" />
    </ListView>
```

Is there anything similar for C++?

Comment: *"I don't know who clicked"* - I don't quite understand. Are you asking which item raised the `SelectionChanged` event? In that case that information is available through the [`SelectionChangedEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.selectionchangedeventargs) passed into your `OnClick` delegate.

Comment: That is correct, but the `OnClick` delegate should stay in the code behind, not in the view model. The `SelectionChangedEventArgs` is control dependent and should not be used in the view model.

Comment: If you don't want your delegate to subscribe to a specific argument type you could always [`as()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/com-ptr#com_ptras-function) or [`try_as()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/com-ptr#com_ptrtry_as-function) in your implementation, once you have determined that you need the extra information. That said, I don't have much experience with the MVVM pattern and its requirements. Never used it, really, since I don't understand the problem it is trying to solve; it just feels needlessly limiting.